# Does apportable (apportable.com) support CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, apportable

I just tried compiling an application with Apportable and got an exception:

> In file included from /Users/jblues/ibipit/voucherBlaster/VoucherBlaster/Client/Utils/RXMLElement+VBMarshalling.h:13:
>   /Users/jblues/ibipit/voucherBlaster/Pods/BuildHeaders/RaptureXML/RXMLElement.h:32:9: fatal error: 
>         'libxml2/libxml/xmlreader.h' file not found

In the Xcode project the header search path for RaptureXML is being set by CocoaPods.

So, first of all, does Apportable currently support CocoaPods?

**Update: (off-topic)** According to research on StackOverflow policies, this question is indeed [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/404201).

Comment: Why don't you ask them?

Comment: this has nothing to do with cocoapods specifically, cp adds code to your project at which point it is no longer involved

Comment: No.  You could extend that concept to everything and post questions here rather than talking to a product's support team or forum.  The site wouldn't be as useful as it currently is.

Comment: Yes you could; most of the questions WRT to iOS/OSX programming issues should probably be asked on the Apple Developer Forum, however that site is effectively dead.

Comment: Last time I used CocoaPods it just creates a new workspace and adds the libraries you want to it. It does change your build settings and all that but if the build runs in Xcode it should work with apportable. Check that the build also runs when using xcodebuild because that's what apportable uses and it sometimes gives different results than building from the IDE.

Comment: I believe the process is that a regular xcodebuild (for iOS) is used to analyze how the project is built, what dependencies there are, etc before the app is built for Android. I noticed that if xcodebuild fails to build (the default release config) then apportable certainly won't work either. There are of course cases where xcodebuild works but apportable doesn't, for example projects within projects within projects are an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apportable does not yet support multiple CocoaPods. [Discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/apportable-discuss/tqgNDUDsl5k) and [Issue](https://code.google.com/p/apportable/issues/detail?id=365).

The background is that CocoaPods depends upon subproject formats and build scripts not yet incorporated into the Apportable build system.