# Apportable with CocoaPods efficient workaround

Tags: cocoapods, apportable

As mentioned before on a Stack Overflow question :  [Does apportable (apportable.com) support CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180743/does-apportable-apportable-com-support-cocoapods)
 **only one CocoaPod** is supported currently with `Apportable`. There is already an open  [issue](https://code.google.com/p/apportable/issues/detail?id=365) on the subject.

I really like `CocoaPods` but also want to be able to port to `Android` easily.

Is there a workaround out there that is more efficient than adding everything to the `header_paths` in the `configuration.json` and copying the sources over to the XCode project manually.

How would one handle this problem more elegantly?